# Rails 3: How can one update Rspec 2.3.0 to 2.4.0 ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, bundler, rspec2

I've tried putting it on my Gemfile and got:

```
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/ You have requested: rspec = 2.4.0

The bundle currently has rspec locked at 2.3.0.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running `bundle update rspec` in your project directory, and then read [the bundler website on updating a dependency.](http://gembundler.com/rationale.html#updating-a-dependency)